# Installed Graphics Card Failure

Tags: graphics-card, display, hardware-failure, graphics

I just bought a refurbished Radeon HD 4650

My power supply says 250w and according to the Radeon website - "400 Watt or greater power supply (550 Watt for ATI CrossFireX™ technology in dual mode) is recommended"

I didn't notice this until I ran into problems and started looking for a solution (bad approach I Know...) Anyway, I installed it and this image is what I get for a short time before the blue screen.

[image]

So my question is, will upgrading my power supply likely fix this issue? Or is this caused by something else. Thanks!

Comment: What computer do you have?

Comment: Lucky for you, the power supply is one of the cheapest and easiest things to replace/test.

Comment: It is a dell studio 540 slim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to find out if the card is functioning properly if you are never supplying it with the required power.  The results of underpowering a card can be artifacts, no display, visuals like you are showing, and sometimes even appearing to work fine until you put a load on the card where you get crashes. etc.  But if there is a problem with the card, you'll never know it if you can't meet the requirements.  And by "you'll never know" I mean the card will always appear to have issues while your power supply is too small.

**WILL** upgrading your power supply fix the issue?  No Idea.  In fact, no one out here can know if it **WILL** fix your issue.  But, until you get a 400 watt power supply, you will never know if it is the cause or not.  You will need to upgrade your power supply to eliminate  it as a suspect.

**EDIT** after seeing your comment about having a Dell Studio Slim (540s) you will need to look for a TFX power supply for that unit.  Something like [this one](http://www.pointtek.ecrater.com/p/8716434/400w-tfx-replacement-dell-power), or [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817338082).  I actually pulled the link for the first one out of the Dell Support Forums.

Comment: @Meowbits this way, at the very least, if there proves to be an issue with the current card, you will have the power supply to use with a replacement.  Although, the type of computer you have does change the price range of the replacement possibilities... as well as the number of PSU replacement possibilities.

Comment: Right, it will be needed either way. Appreciate the reply.

Comment: @Meowbits added a bit to the answer for you